# Finding email on MySQL database with NODE.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to authenticate an user with a simple login. I'm using node.js and mysql in my project, what I am doing is checking if the email exists in the field email y my accounts table. I am passing the query results to a constant row and afterwards checking its length, if it returns more than 0 it means it found something (?), heres my snippet:

```
console.log(testEmail) //it does receives an email
console.log(password) //it does receives a password

const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?', [testEmail.email]);
console.log(rows); //row comes out empty
```

Here is the complete method:

```
passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async(req, username, password, done) => {
    const {email} = req.body;
    const testEmail = {
        email
    };
    console.log(testEmail)
    console.log(password)

    const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?', [testEmail.email]);
    console.log(rows);
    if (rows.length > 0) {
        const user = rows[0];
        const validPassword = await helpers.matchPassword(password, user.password);
        if(validPassword){
            done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'Welcome!'));
        } else{
            done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Incorrect password'));
        }
    } else{
        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Email not found'));
    }
}));
```

Adding the console results for email and password:

```
{ email: 'irwin.inoa@gmail.com' }
123456
```

Adding my table definition:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL
```

Any idea on how to fix this, am I missing something?

UPDATE:

As provided below, this is fixed by passing the email property through the object testEmail.

```
testEmail.email.
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: probably an IIFE like `(async function(){
  const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?', [testEmail]);
console.log(rows);
})();` could help.

Comment: ```
passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async(req, username, password, done) => {
    const {email} = req.body;
    const testEmail = {
        email
    };
    console.log(testEmail)
    console.log(password)
    
    const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?', [testEmail]);
    console.log(rows);
    if (rows.length > 0) {
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could have an error in your query but since you are not try/catch your query then you do not know what happened. You may want to do something like this:

```
let rows = [];
try{
   rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?', [testEmail.email]);
}catch(err){
   console.log("Query Error", err);
}
```

Comment: Returns undefined

Comment: Okay I tried with the let rows = [ ], it still returns empty, does it has to do something with the way it is stored? It shows the email im passing in the terminal like this:

`{ email: 'irwin.inoa@gmail.com' }`

Comment: Oh, seeing your full code now. I found that you store your email inside an object. so in the query you need to use `[testEmail.email]`

Answer (score -1):

## Original answer

As I'm seeing in the [docs](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool), the `pool.query()` function has a callback or returns a promise. You can catch the result as follows:

```js
// callback

pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?', [testEmail], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {  
        return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack);
    }
    console.log(rows);
});


// promise

pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?', [testEmail])
.then(rows => {
    return console.log(rows);
})
.catch(err => {
    return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack);
});
```

## Edit

Okay, so just for testing, try this code to see if the table is correct. Maybe we are not passing correctly the parameters to the query.

```js
// return all records of the table

pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts LIMIT 100', [], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {  
        return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack);
    }
    console.log(rows);
});

// Another way to pass the parameter

pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = $1::text', [testEmail], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {  
        return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack);
    }
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Comment: Hello! I tried this method, results.rows returned undefined

Comment: What about just printing `results`, what does it returns?

Comment: I get this: [ ]

Comment: Do you have any records on that `accounts` table? Does the `testEmail` you are passing has related records in the table?

Comment: Yes sir, these are mytable properties:

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL